# Usar API javascript

Tags: javascript, api

Estoy usando un programa que tiene una api para enviarle información,
lo que necesito es que al presionar un botón se ejecute esta URL:

[http://192.168.1.142:5000/api/v1/invokeTemplateFunction?playserver=OVERLAY&playchannel=1&playlayer=2&webplayout=2&function=updateGFX&params=aa|aa|aa](http://192.168.1.142:5000/api/v1/invokeTemplateFunction?playserver=OVERLAY&playchannel=1&playlayer=2&webplayout=2&function=updateGFX&params=aa%7Caa%7Caa)

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin un `iframe`?

Comment: A que te refieres cuando dices "que se ejecute"?

Comment: necesito enviar lo que pone como params con la api, por eso pensaba lo del iframe, pero necesito enviar mas de un paramatro cada vez, por  ello preguntaba si hay una forma de hacerlo sin usar iframes

Comment: Ahora no tengo tiempo para elaborar una respuesta pero investiga sobre **fetch** es la api de js, en un rato elaboro una respuesta si aún no tienes una

Comment: vale gracias, intentare investigar algo, de todas formas si en algún momento tienes tiempo te agradecería que hicieras una respuesta

Comment: vale, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Listo respuesta publicada :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124610/discussion-between-javier-cuenca-martin-and-christian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder enviar una solicitud HTTP a alguna URL o endpoint podemos hacer uso de la api de JavaScript `fetch()`, eso también se puede realizar con JQuery y Ajax. Ajax esta basado en las solicitudes HTTP, el cual envía una solicitud a una URL y espera la respuesta, todo esto sin recargar la pagina, antiguamente se  utilizaba `XMLHttpRequest` para realizar cosas así, pero en una actualización de ECMAScript (JavaScript) se agrego esta funcionalidad de `fetch()` para realizar peticiones HTTP de una mejor forma, esta es una tecnología aun en fase de prueba y no es soportada por todos los navegadores (si utilizas las ultimas versione Chrome no tendrás problemas). Bueno y como lo usamos?

Primero debemos de saber como funciona la [API FETCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), al usar fect esto nos devolverá un callback que podemos manejar como queramos (función callback, then, async/await), mayormente es utilizado con `.then` que vendría siendo la promesa.

```js
fetch('http://example.com/myjson.json') #enviamos la solicitud a un archivo JSON
  .then(response => response.json()) //devuelve un objeto Promise
  .then(data => console.log(data)); //obtenemos los datos
```

Listo eso es todo, como dije se puede hacer peticiones a cualquier URL o endpoint, ahora pasemos a tu problema

Si quieres mandar una petición a tu [url](http://192.168.1.142:5000/api/v1/invokeTemplateFunction?playserver=OVERLAY&playchannel=1&playlayer=2&webplayout=2&function=updateGFX&params=aa%7Caa%7Caa) Lo puedes hacer, solo reemplaza la url y especificas el tipo de petición HTTP `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` o `DELETE`, si no se especifica por defecto es `GET`.

```js
let url =  "http://192.168.1.142:5000/api/v1/invokeTemplateFunction?"

let params = "playserver=OVERLAY&playchannel=1&playlayer=2&webplayout=2&function=updateGFX&params=aa|aa|aa"

fetch(url+params, {  #enviamos la solicitud la URL
      method: "POST" #especificamos el metodo
   }) 
  .then(response => response.json()) //devuelve un objeto Promise
  .then(data => console.log(data)); //obtenemos los datos
```

Aquí solo tendrás que manejar la respuesta según lo que esperas `.text()`, `.json()`, etc.

Si quieres poner mas parámetros o hacerlo de forma dinámica solo concatenas y para mejor legibilidad usas *backtikcs* (``` `` ```).

```js
let url =  "http://192.168.1.142:5000/api/v1/invokeTemplateFunction?"

let params = "playserver=OVERLAY&playchannel=1"

let otherParam = "&params=aa|aa|aa"

params = `${params}${otherParam}`

fetch(`${url}${params}`, {  #enviamos la solicitud la URL
      method: "POST" #especificamos el metodo
   }) 
  .then(response => response.json()) //devuelve un objeto Promise
  .then(data => console.log(data)); //obtenemos los datos
```

También se puede enviar mas parámetros, como headers, content-type, etc. Puedes leer mas en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)